# Plotting in GTK 3 Fortran in a drawing-area when a button is clicked

Tags: user-interface, plot, fortran, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As a beginner i created in a short time a GTK 3 Fortran Code close to examples for line-plotting into a drawing-area triggered by a button. The plotting is done via g_signal_connect in a function draw. Unfortunately this works with my Code only for the Signal 'draw' from the drawing-area. The Signal 'clicked' from the button leads to an invalid Memory Reference. How can i overcome this Problem? Thank you for help and sorry for the trivial Question. I found different threads for similar Questions, but no solution in Fortran.

```
! GtkWidget event:
  function draw (widget, my_cairo_context, gdata) result(ret)  bind(c)
    use iso_c_binding, only: c_ptr, c_int
    implicit none
    integer(c_int)     :: ret
    type(c_ptr), value :: widget, my_cairo_context, gdata
    call cairo_set_source_rgb(my_cairo_context, 1d0, 0d0, 0d0)
    call cairo_set_line_width(my_cairo_context, 0.5d0)
    call cairo_move_to(my_cairo_context, 50d0, 5d0)
    call cairo_line_to(my_cairo_context, 150d0, 150d0)
    call cairo_stroke(my_cairo_context)
    ret = FALSE
  end function draw

program gtkFortran
  call gtk_init ()

! Create a window:
  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
  call gtk_window_set_default_size(window, 500, 500)
  call gtk_window_set_title(window, "Press Start For Plotting"//c_null_char)
  call g_signal_connect (window, "destroy"//c_null_char, c_funloc(destroy))

! Create a grid:
  table = gtk_grid_new ()
  call gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(table, TRUE)
  call gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(table, TRUE)
  call gtk_widget_set_margin_start (table, 10_c_int)
  call gtk_widget_set_margin_end (table, 10_c_int)
  call gtk_widget_set_margin_top (table, 10_c_int)
  call gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom (table, 10_c_int)  
  call gtk_container_add (window, table)

! Create a drawing-area:
  area = gtk_drawing_area_new()
  call gtk_grid_attach(table, area, 0_c_int, 6_c_int, 3_c_int, 6_c_int)
  call g_signal_connect (area, "draw"//c_null_char, c_funloc(draw))
  call gtk_widget_queue_draw_area (area, 0_c_int, 6_c_int, 3_c_int, 6_c_int)

! Create a button:
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Start"//c_null_char)
  call gtk_grid_attach(table, button, 0_c_int, 0_c_int, 1_c_int, 1_c_int)
  call g_signal_connect (button, "clicked"//c_null_char, c_funloc(draw))

  call gtk_widget_show_all (window)
  call gtk_main ()
end program gtkFortran
```

Comment: The easiest way may be to visit the gtk-fortran github project.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your code looks incomplete. Your variables are not declared. Be sure to show the exact full code you have.

Comment: As wished in 'How to Ask' i reduced the Code to shorten and clarify the Problem. All variables are declared and there is no Problem to compile and run the Code, except that a click on the button produces a core Dump in function 'draw' but a Signal to the drawing-area produces a draw in function draw.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the prototype of "clicked" callback function is:

```
void user_function (GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
```

and the `my_cairo_context` pointer is therefore missing.

You should create a callback function for your button, where you will call `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()`.

See: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html

> Draw signals are normally delivered when a drawing area first comes onscreen, or when it’s covered by another window and then uncovered. You can also force an expose event by adding to the “damage region” of the drawing area’s window; gtk_widget_queue_draw_area() and gdk_window_invalidate_rect() are equally good ways to do this.